# How to prove this using induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

The problem is :

Using induction, prove that $ (\frac{n+1}{n})^n \le n $ for $ n>3 $

and then using that prove that the sequence $ 1 , 2 ^ {(1/2)}, 3 ^ {1/3},4^{1/4} ..  $ is decreasing starting from the third term

Comment: You can almost as easily show that $(1+\frac1n)^n<3$, the actual limit of this increasing sequence is $e$.

Comment: Welcome to [MATHEMATICS](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Please tell us what are you tried up to now for this problem.

Comment: Calvin lin helped me, thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $$ \frac{ (n+2) ^{n+1} } { (n+1)^{n+2} } \leq \frac{ (n+1)^{n} } {n^{n+1} } .$$

This follows because $ n^2 + 2n \leq n^2 + 2n + 1 $.

Use this to complete the induction.

---

The next part of the problem follows directly from the induction statement.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of the inequality

I'm stucked here...

For $n=3$ the inequality is true. So now, checking for $n+1$   ..   

$\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \le n+1$

Comment: I understood now, thanks!